# File.AppendAllText is not member ' string'

Tags: vb.net

```vb
Imports System.IO

Module MainModule

    Sub Main()
        Dim sourcePath As String = "D:\GE"
        Dim targetPath As String = "C:\lstwhite"
        Dim logFile As String = "C:\lstwhite\Log.txt"

        Dim dataFiles() As String = Directory.GetFiles(sourcePath, "DA*.PAQ")
        Dim ptrinFiles() As String = Directory.GetFiles(sourcePath, "PTN*.PAQ")

        For Each file As String In dataFiles.Concat(ptrinFiles)
            Dim fileInfo As New FileInfo(file)
            Dim fileName As String = fileInfo.Name
            Dim targetFile As String = Path.Combine(targetPath, fileName)
            Dim fileCreationTime As DateTime = fileInfo.LastWriteTime
            Dim timeDiff As TimeSpan = DateTime.Now.Subtract(fileCreationTime)
            If timeDiff.TotalHours < 2 Then
                fileInfo.MoveTo(targetFile)
                File.AppendAllText(logFile, fileName & vbCrLf)
            End If
        Next
    End Sub

End Module
```

> File.AppendAllText(logFile, fileName & vbCrLf) error bc 30456 is not member ' string'

Comment: And what is your question? In the future, you should explain what you need and what doesn't work. Placing just the code and the exception is not enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a conflict between your local variable `file` and the class `File` from the `System.IO`. Don't forget that VB is case-insensitive. The VB compiler resolves the name from the closest scope. In your case, for the `File.AppendAllText(logFile, fileName & vbCrLf)` line, it is the `file` variable from the same block scope of the `For Each` block.

The `file` variable is of type `String`, which doesn't contain any `AppendAllText` function. That explains the exception.

Your `Imports System.IO` doesn't help here. You need to explicitly specify the fully qualified class name for the `File` class:

```
System.IO.File.AppendAllText(logFile, fileName & vbCrLf)
```